# Printing out content of class pointer from within a vector container C++

Tags: c++

We store a pointer to an object in a vector and want to print out objects contents.

I have tried the following:

```
vector<Clothing*> obj2;
obj2.push_back(new Clothing(2, 3, "Hlace"));
for (auto i : obj2)
{
    cout << i << " ";
}
```

and

```
vector<Clothing*> obj2;
obj2.push_back(new Clothing(2, 3, "Hlace"));
int list = obj2.size();
for (int i = 0; i < obj2.size(); i++)
{
    cout << obj2[i] << endl;
}
```

first code just returns an address, and the second one basically return "1", because the .size() only takes in first argument I suppose?

I just need to print out content of obj2, therefore: 2, 3, Hlace.

Comment: `cout << *i << " ";` Should do the trick

Comment: Nope "no operator << matches these operands".

Comment: obj2.size(); returns a value 1.

Comment: Did you overload `operator <<`?

Comment: obj2.size(); returns 1 because there's only one element in the vector. What were you expecting?

Comment: well our assistant teacher basically wrote this on table, as an example to follow and do it this way, but then we ended the class.

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned the declaration of `Clothing`. In order to use it with `<<`, you need to overload the operator `<<`.

Assuming that you overload it correctly, all you need to do is to dereference the pointer using `*`.

For the first, use `*i`.

For the second, use `*obj2[i]`.

A working example ([Demo](https://ideone.com/WwIKac)) to illustrate the overload and its use:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Clothing {
    int x, y;
    string z;
    Clothing(int x, int y, string z)
      : x(x), y(y), z(z)
      {}
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Clothing& c) { 
  os << c.x << ' ' << c.y << ' ' << c.z << endl;
}

void try1() {
  vector<Clothing*> obj2;
  obj2.push_back(new Clothing(2, 3, "Hlace"));
  for (auto i : obj2)
  {
    cout << *i << " ";
  } 
}

void try2() {
  vector<Clothing*> obj2;
  obj2.push_back(new Clothing(2, 3, "Hlace"));
  int list = obj2.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < obj2.size(); i++)
  {
    cout << *obj2[i] << endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  try1();
  try2();
}
```

Side question: Do you really have a legitimate reason to store the pointer in the vector, instead of the object itself?

Comment: Especially considering the pointer points to dynamically allocated memory, I see no point in not using `emplace_back` instead. Is there a context in which this actually makes sense?

Comment: Got it. Thanks to both you and Ayxan.

Comment: @KL give credit where it is due and [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Ayxan Perhaps, with custom allocators with `new` and `delete` overloaded. Can't say whether that's legit enough.

Comment: It's an assignment rule, I didn't come up with it.

Answer (score 1):

> first code just returns an address

The first program prints the address stored in the vector.

> and the second one basically return "1"

The second program also prints the address stored in the vector. Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/557db2d117cc654f

It's unclear why you think otherwise.

> I just need to print out content of obj2, therefore: 2, 3, Hlace.

You can access the pointed object by indirecting though the pointer:

```
obj2[i]->some_memeber
```